# Module 'pcntl' already loaded in unknown on line 0

Tags: ubuntu, apache

После установки *pcntl* наталкиваюсь на ошибку при запуске тестов (`make test`)

> module 'pcntl' already loaded in unknown on line 0

При этом на множестве форумов одно и то же - закомментировать в `*.ini` файлах строку

> disable_functions =
>   pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl

Нашел её в файле `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`, закомментировал, перезагрузил *apache2*, не помогло. Перезагрузка сервера не помогла.

Как исправить эту ошибку?

*ubuntu 14.04*
*apache 2.4.7*
*php5 5.5.9*

Comment: Это просто значит, что у васдважды подгружается модуль. Найдите в инишниках строчку extension=(что-то pcntl) и закомментируйте ее.

Comment: искал по слову pcntl и не смог ничего найти. Поэтому и обратился сюда :)

Comment: `make test` — это вы в командной строке выполняете в каталоге с исходниками? тогда, вероятно, в процессе тестов выполняется программа `php` из пакета `php5-cli`, а в описании пакета (`apt-cache show php5-cli`) написано: *the following extensions are built in ... **pcntl** ...*.

Comment: выполняю в папке `/opt/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/pcntl`

Comment: @Relajado, вы поняли смысл процитированного текста? «следующие расширения встроены: ... **pcntl** ...». в программе `php` уже присутствует эта функциональность. проверьте: команда `$ php -r 'pcntl_exec("/bin/date");'` напечатает текущее время.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, смысл я понял. Команда выполняется. Как тогда мне быть с тестами?  Прошу прощения за глупые вопросы, я только недавно начал работать с UNIX и раньше никогда не работал с модулями для php и тестами

Comment: @Relajado, «как быть» зависит от того, чего вы, собственно, хотите добиться. чтобы работали функции *pcntl-...*? так они и так работают, «из коробки».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin просто для меня остаётся загадкой почему тесты "из коробки" не работают :)

Comment: тесты чего? скомпилированного вами расширения? насколько я понимаю — и не должны они работать: расширение уже присутствует. оно встроено в программу php, и при попытке загрузить **второй** экземпляр (тот что **вы** скомпилировали) php вполне резонно выдаёт вам сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: зайдём с другой стороны: зачем вы компилируете расширение, которое и так уже есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как минимум в *debian*-основных дистрибутивах (*ubuntu* — один из них) расширение *pcntl* уже встроено в программы, идущие в следующих пакетах:

```
$ apt-cache search pcntl
php5-cgi - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
php5-cli - command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
libphp5-embed - HTML-embedded scripting language (Embedded SAPI library)
```

цитата из, например, описания пакета *php5-cli*:

> the following extensions are built in: ... **pcntl** ...

---

в правдивости этой информации легко убедиться, вызвав какую-нибудь *pcntl*-функцию. например, здесь функция `pcntl_exec` загружает программу `/bin/date`, которая выводит текущую дату и время:

```
$ php -r 'pcntl_exec("/bin/date");'
Sat Sep 26 01:47:04 MSK 2015
```